# SSIS - Fuzzy Grouping Column increment

Tags: ssis, fuzzy

I tried using fuzzy grouping for a column and added other columns as a pass through but value of the column for which the pass through is inhibited gets incremented.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: `OrderId` is passed through the Fuzzy Grouping. Before it, the value is 1, after the component, it is 2?

Comment: @billinkc The length of the number is increased randomly while passing it through the fuzzy grouping

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Its an issue in the version SQL Server 2008 R2 and it is not replicating in SQL Server 2012